# What do you call the frequent conjunction {juxtaposition} of two words?

Tags: expressions, terminology, single-word-requests

The statement that I want to make is:

> "Impostor syndrome" ... why does this (conjunction of words) sneak into every text I read these days?

What is the right or best expression for "conjunction of words"? In the statement I don't want to refer to the syndrome itself, but rather to the expression. If it was one word instead of two I would want to say

> ... why does this *word* sneak into every text I read these days.

However, writing

> ________ why do these two words sneak into every text I read these days.

would miss the point, because it's not these two words that sneak into every text at various location but rather their conjunction.

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is "phrase"

Comment: Thanks. But does phrase not require a minimal amount of grammatical structure... something that can stand by itself?

Comment: If you define "phrase" only as a grammatical structure, then Impostor Syndrom is a basic Noun Phrase, with the first noun modifying the second, similar to Police Station or Muffin Tin. But the word "phrase" has broader meanings, including "a brief expression". See Merriam-Webster: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/phrase

Comment: expression, term,  compound word, buzzword, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious choice is to call it an **expression**:

> A word or phrase, especially an idiomatic one, used to convey an idea.
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/expression)</sub>

(In fact, you've already used this in the question.)

Alternatively, you can call it a **phrase**.

Answer (score 3):

A word I actually only started using after following this site is [**collocation**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/collocation):

> [Oxford]
>
> **1** *Linguistics*
> The habitual juxtaposition of a particular word with another word or words with a frequency greater than chance.
> *‘the words have a similar range of collocation’*
>
> **1.1** *count noun* A pair or group of words that are habitually juxtaposed.
> *‘‘strong tea’ and ‘heavy drinker’ are typical English collocations’*
>
> **2** The action of placing things side by side or in position.
> *‘the collocation of the two pieces’*

There are actually dictionaries, such as [OzDictionary](http://www.ozdic.com/), that are devoted to collocations.

(Ironically enough in terms of this answer, that site doesn't list "imposter syndrome" as a collocation—the closest it located for me was ["Californian syndrome."](http://www.ozdic.com/collocation-dictionary/syndrome) However, any such resource is only going to list *common* collocations, not ones that you might be personally noticing.)

Comment: Thanks @Jason Bassford. This is a great word, that will do the job. And thanks for the reference to the OzDictionary.

Comment: "imposter syndrome" is not a collocation, it's a name for a *specific* syndrome. Would you say that "Down's Syndrome" is a collocation? No, it's not, it's a medical expression, it's a name for a genetic disorder.

Comment: A typical collocation are things like "upstairs bedroom" instead of  "upper floor bedroom" or "twin beds" instead of "two single beds"